# ¿Como crear elementos <area> con javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, img

Se puede crear "areas" desde javascript? teniendo la información(coordenadas) guardadas en una base de datos?

Comment: hablas del elemento textarea?

Comment: No, cuando creas un mapa de imagen <map>... las áreas de ese mapa, se crean con coordenadas(y hay q poner también si se trata de un ractángulo, circulo o polígono). Lo que yo quiero saber es si ese "<area>" se puede crear automáticamente al cargar la página, con js, trayendo las coordenadas previamente guardadas en una BD.

Comment: por ejemplo, un div, se crea de la siguiente manera...

Comment: `element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = 'rectangle';
            element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
            element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
            canvas.appendChild(element)
            console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
            canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";`

Comment: Listo ya comprendí, me estaba confuendiendo

Comment: Se puede hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí se puede hacer. Tomé el ejemplo de [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) para esta respuesta, agregando el área para `JS` por medio de Javascript.

En este primer ejemplo, pasa el mouse sobre `JS`, no hay área creada aún. Haz clic en el botón *Agregar JS* y vuelve a pasar el mouse sobre esa sección, ahora ya hay área.

```js
function agregarJs() {
    // Obtener mapa
    let mapa = document.getElementById('mapa');
    // Crear área y asignar atributos
    let js = document.createElement('area');
    // Aquí defines el tipo de forma
    js.shape = 'poly';
    js.coords = '130,147,200,107,130,4,59,107';
    js.href = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript';
    js.target = '_blank';
    // Agregar área al mapa
    mapa.appendChild(js);
}
```

```css
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 260px;
    height: 232px;
}

button {
    display:block;
    margin:10px auto;
}
```

```html
<map name="infographic" id="mapa">
    <area shape="poly" coords="130,147,200,107,254,219,130,228"
          href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML"
          target="_blank" alt="HTML" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="130,147,130,228,6,219,59,107"
          href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS"
          target="_blank" alt="CSS" />
</map>
<img usemap="#infographic" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/mdn-info2.png" alt="MDN infographic" />

<button onclick="agregarJs();">Agregar JS</button>
```

Puedes agregar el área al mapa al cargar la página:

```js
// Suponiendo que obtuviste las coordenadas como JSON o arreglo
let coords = [130,147,200,107,130,4,59,107];

window.onload = function() {
    // Obtener mapa
    let mapa = document.getElementById('mapa');
    // Crear área y asignar atributos
    let js = document.createElement('area');
    // Aquí defines el tipo de forma
    js.shape = 'poly';
    // Creas una cadena con las coordenadas, separando por comas
    js.coords = coords.join(',');
    js.href = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript';
    js.target = '_blank';
    // Agregar área al mapa
    mapa.appendChild(js);
}
```

```css
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 260px;
    height: 232px;
}
```

```html
<map name="infographic" id="mapa">
    <area shape="poly" coords="130,147,200,107,254,219,130,228"
          href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML"
          target="_blank" alt="HTML" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="130,147,130,228,6,219,59,107"
          href="https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS"
          target="_blank" alt="CSS" />
</map>
<img usemap="#infographic" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/mdn-info2.png" alt="MDN infographic" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!